# Provoke conflict when using Android Snapshots (Game Play Services)

Tags: android, google-play-services, snapshot

I have implemented functions to save and load snapshots using the Game API from Google Play Services. The next step I am working on is to handle conflicts when there is more then one snapshot. And here comes the problem.

In my understanding a conflict should occure when doing the following:

1. Save a snapshot after making game progress
2. Sign out (Google Play Services)
3. Delete all app data
4. Start game again and make some progress
5. Sign in (Google Play Services)
6. Save a new snapshop
7. Load snapshop

Unfortunately in my case no conflict occures. Instead the current game progress is being saved (step 6) and loading (step 7) just returns this snapshop. There is no indicator that snapshot (step 1) was overwritten - resulting in loosing game progress.

Code for saving:

```
private void executeSave() {
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = App.getGoogleApiHelper().getmGoogleApiClient();
            Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult openResult = Games.Snapshots.open(googleApiClient, getSavegameFilename(), true).await();
            Status resultStatus = openResult.getStatus();

            Log.d(TAG, "openstatus is: " + resultStatus.getStatusMessage());

            if(resultStatus.isSuccess()) {
                byte[] localSavegame = getPersistingManager().readBytes();
                if(localSavegame != null)  {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Going to save:" + getPersistingManager().read());
                    createSnapshot(openResult.getSnapshot(), localSavegame).await();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


private PendingResult<Snapshots.CommitSnapshotResult> createSnapshot(Snapshot snapshot, byte[] data) {
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = App.getGoogleApiHelper().getmGoogleApiClient();
    snapshot.getSnapshotContents().writeBytes(data);
    SnapshotMetadataChange metadataChange = new SnapshotMetadataChange.Builder().build();
    return Games.Snapshots.commitAndClose(googleApiClient, snapshot, metadataChange);
}
```

Code for loading:

```
private void executeLoad() {
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = App.getGoogleApiHelper().getmGoogleApiClient();
            Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result = Games.Snapshots.open(googleApiClient, getSavegameFilename(), true).await();
            processResult(result, 0);
        }
    });
}

private void processResult(Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result, int retryCount) {
    Status resultStatus = result.getStatus();
    retryCount++;

    if(resultStatus.isSuccess()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "No conflict, thats great!");
        handleSuccess(result);
    } else if (resultStatus.getStatusCode() == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_SNAPSHOT_CONFLICT) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Aww... a conflict!");
        handleConflict(result, retryCount);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error while getting savegame, status message: " + resultStatus.getStatusMessage());
    }
}
```

When performing the steps from above this is happening:

1) Save a snapshot after making game progress

```
absRemotePersistMgmt: openstatus is: STATUS_OK
absRemotePersistMgmt: Going to save:{"solvedQuestions":{"1":[],"2":[1]}}
```

6) Save a new snapshot

```
absRemotePersistMgmt: openstatus is: STATUS_OK
absRemotePersistMgmt: Going to save:{"solvedQuestions":{"1":[1,2],"2":[]}}
```

7) Load snapshop

```
absRemotePersistMgmt: No conflict, thats great!
```

What am I missing?

Sources I used:

- https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHc2RBZs5T0
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naQhSkzNGAI